# Angular Kendo UI show Grid items as hyperlink

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I am new to Angular Kendo UI and I have am going through Kendo UI Grid System on the [website](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/).

My grid data has reports with name, date and link as below:

```
gridData: IReport[] = [
    {
      "date": "9/5/2018",
      "reportName": "Report 1",
      "reportLink": "http://google.com/",
      "reportStatus": "Success"
    },
    {
      "date": "9/7/2018",
      "reportName": "Report 2",
      "reportLink": "http://yahoo.com/",
      "reportStatus": "Success"
    },
    {
      "date": "8/5/2018",
      "reportName": "Report 3",
      "reportLink": "http://msn.com/",
      "reportStatus": "Success"
    },]
```

I want to display this grid on UI with reportLink as a hyperlink. This is how my html looks:

```
<kendo-grid  [resizable]="true" [data]="gridData" [height]="500">
  <kendo-grid-column field="date" title="Date"  width="40">
  </kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="reportName" title="Report Name" width="50">
  </kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="reportLink" title="Report Link" width="50"> 
      <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem *ngFor="let data of gridData">
            <a href="{{data.reportLink}}">{{data.reportLink}}</a>
      </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="reportStatus" title="Report Status" width="80">
  </kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

I display the link I am looping through gridData and displaying it as  tag.

```
  <kendo-grid-column field="reportLink" title="Report Link" width="50"> 
      <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem *ngFor="let data of gridData">
            <a href="{{data.reportLink}}">{{data.reportLink}}</a>
      </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-column>
```

My issue is that the report link only shows http:google.com for all the report. 
[image]

What am I doing wrong?   I expect to see google.com, yahoo.com and msn.com as my report links.

Any pointers? Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try binding directly to dataItem. You do not need the *ngFor.

```
 <kendo-grid-column field="reportLink" title="Report Link" width="50"> 
      <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
            <a [href]="dataItem.reportLink">{{dataItem.reportLink}}</a>
      </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-column>
```